# ¿Estoy usando bien "hipócrita"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, significado, sinónimos

Mi hermano suele decirme seguido mientras cenamos que no coma directo de la fuente y que me sirva en mi plato, y después él come de la fuente.

Yo le digo "hipócrita" pero mi madre me dice que no es un hipócrita ya que la palabra no significa eso. ¿Estoy usando bien esta palabra?

Comment: Mucha gente usa la palabra así, aunque como dice Diego la definición no concuerda perfectamente con esta situación.  Tu madre preferiría quizás *inconsistente*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeras te diría que yo entiendo que una persona hipócrita es aquella que dice una cosa (o te dice que tú tienes que hacer cierta cosa, seguir ciertas normas, etc.) pero luego hace otra cosa completamente distinta. Como si tuviera dos varas para medir, una para ella y otra para los demás, o si directamente se saltase sus propias reglas. Yo también habría tachado a tu hermano de hipócrita.

En estos casos suele ser buena idea preguntar `"Mamá, ¿qué significa entonces '*hipócrita*' (Dame tu definición)? ¿Cómo se le dice a alguien que te dice que tú tienes que seguir ciertas normas y luego él hace lo contrario (como hace mi hermano)?"` y ver qué entienden esas personas que significa el término. Luego, comparas con la definición oficial.

La definición de `hipócrita` en el diccionario es:

> **[hipócrita](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KTCowWw)**
>
> 1. adj. Que actúa con **hipocresía**. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Propio de la persona hipócrita. Sonrisa hipócrita.
>
> **[hipocresía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KTAiwim)**
>
> Fingimiento de cualidades o sentimientos contrarios a los que verdaderamente se tienen o experimentan.

Entendería que es casi un "tecnicismo" que en este caso tu hermano no muestra "cualidades o sentimientos" y por eso no está siendo un hipócrita.

La descripción del diccionario queda un poco corta para mi gusto. Otras referencias, como esta [discusión sobre su etimología](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hipo.crita) apuntan a que una persona hipócrita

> finge sentimientos que no tiene, o **expresa ideales que no sigue**

que se adapta mejor a tu caso (decir "No hagas eso. No debemos comer directamente  de la fuente. No es lo correcto" y luego hacer justo lo contrario).

Quizá tu madre entiende que al comportamiento de tu hermano se le puede tachar de `falso` o de `incoherente`, pero no de hipócrita, pues tu hermano no "**finge** cualidades o sentimientos". Una persona hipócrita es aquella que "finge una cualidad, sentimiento, virtud u opinión que no tiene" y *técnicamente* tu hermano no está diciendo que sea más virtuoso o mejor que tú ya que él no come de la fuente (y luego come de la fuente).

### Básicamente, no es un hipócrita si no está diciendo "no comas directamente de la fuente que yo no lo hago" cuando la verdad es que el sí lo hace.

En cualquier caso, el "expresar ideales que no se tienen" es también incoherente.

Así que es cierto que tu hermano, técnicamente, no es un hipócrita pero desde luego es un:

- **incoherente** ([coherencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9ggcmPj): Actitud lógica y consecuente con los principios que se profesan) e **incongruente** ([congruente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AJwFS2g): Conveniente, *coherente*, lógico.) y demás sinónimos.
- [sermoneador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XfWpYtH) (Que sermonea o acostumbra reprender.)
- [absurdo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0DERMh7) (Chocante, **contradictorio**.)
- [injusto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LdRAP4Y) (¿quizá tu hermano piensa que él *sí* puede comer de la fuente mientras que tú no? En este caso no estaría siendo un hipócrita, pero se estaría poniendo directamente por encima tuyo. Si siendo hermanos no tenéis una relación de iguales, es razonable decir que su comportamiento no es justo ni equitativo).
- [torticero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a8Lk4H9): Injusto, o que no se arregla a las leyes o a la razón.

Suerte en la próxima cena. Dedícale a tu hermano alguno de estos *halagos* y luego dejas caer que la palabra del día es

> Moralizante, de [Moralizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PmNsRnG):
>
> Reformar las malas costumbres **enseñando las buenas**.

y dile que si quiere enseñarte algo, que lo haga con el ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias, yo había encontrado el término "inconsistente" que creo también se adecúa al caso. Y gracias por la oportuna palabra del día :)

Comment: En el contexto, diría que "hipócrita" es un poco altisonante. Yo usaría "caradura".