# ¿Cómo se dice a la persona que boicotea una acción para luego vanagloriarse de que no haya podido realizarse?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

Al hilo de la interesante pregunta [¿Estoy usando bien "hipócrita"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21763/1674) pensé en una caso similar:

Imaginemos que eres atleta y quieres correr los 1500 metros en menos de 4 minutos ([una marcaza](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/roger-bannister-breaks-four-minutes-mile), vaya). En eso que alguien que te quiere mal empieza a sabotearte: te dice constantemente que no podrás correr en ese tiempo, te llama por la noche para que no descanses bien, te impide entrenar en la pista de atletismo, etc. Para rematarlo, el día de la competición te esconde las zapatillas de correr y tienes que usar otras.

Como el *boicot* ha funcionado, al final no consigues el objetivo y esa persona va y te dice:

> ¿Ves? Ya te dije yo que no podrías.

Esa persona, además de mala, está ejerciendo de juez y de parte: juzga algo mientras aboga por una de las opciones. ¿Existe algún nombre para esta persona, un adjetivo que la califique o una expresión que la ejemplarice? Lo de *juez y parte* es la única opción que me imagino.

Comment: Podría debatirse si la crítica constante previa no es también en sí misma parte del sabotaje. *Juez y parte* suena a doblez (el juez mantiene las formas de la neutralidad), no como en este caso donde el crítico/saboteador no guarda las apariencias.

Comment: No se me ocurre otra palabra que la que propone @walen, es lo que yo había pensado también. *Juez y parte* es alguien que juzga algo estando involucrado, por lo que no puede ser neutral, pero tu ejemplo es distinto, él hace que ocurra su augurio.

Comment: Yo iba a sugerir [catastrofista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7vN6RHn), pero me doy cuenta de que una persona catastrofista no necesariamente te sabotea.

Comment: @Diego buena idea en tanto en cuanto esa persona _quiere_ la catástrofe.

Comment: Con un amigo así ¿quien necesita enemigos?

Answer (score 3):

A fin de no usar términos como el que he sugerido en [un comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-a-la-persona-que-boicotea-una-acci%C3%B3n-para-luego-vanagloriarse-de-q?noredirect=1#comment34210_21769), que puede resultar algo fuerte, propongo este otro:

> **[necio, cia](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=necio)**
>
> 3. adj. Terco y [porfiado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Th0VLmV) en lo que hace o dice.

(De lo cual podría convenirse, por sinonimia, que la persona que mencionas es lisa y llanamente [gilipollas](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=gilipollas)... pero entonces estaríamos volviendo a términos no adecuados, supongo).

El uso de **necio** para personas que obran con maldad solo por demostrar que tienen razón, viene de antiguo:

> *Pues el **necio** habla necedades, y su corazón se inclina hacia el mal, para practicar la impiedad y hablar falsedad contra el Señor, para mantener con hambre al hambriento y para privar de bebida al sediento.*
>   <sub>[Isaías 32:6](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/Espa%C3%B1al/Isa%C3%ADas/32/6)</sub>

También hay [ejemplos más recientes](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Necedad), claro. Algunos que podrían cuadrar:

> *Se conocen infinitas clases de **necios**; la más deplorable es la de los parlanchines empeñados en demostrar que tienen talento.*
>   <sub>Santiago Ramón y Cajal</sub>

O también:

> *Propio de todo hombre es el errar. Pero de nadie, sino del **necio**, el mantenerse en el error.*
>   <sub>Juan Luis Vives</sub>

La persona que describes, proclama que no eres capaz de conseguir una cosa; y, viendo que podrías conseguirla, interviene para forzar tu fracaso, y cree que de esta forma ha demostrado que tenía razón. Este es un comportamiento **necio**, y esa persona es **necia**.

---

El problema con el término que buscas, es que debe unificar dos actitudes distintas:

- Por una parte, la de la persona que predica y se regodea en la desgracia ajena; para esto podrían servir los términos *agorera*, *infausta*, o [el propuesto por Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-a-la-persona-que-boicotea-una-acci%C3%B3n-para-luego-vanagloriarse-de-q#comment34217_21769): *catastrofista*.
- Por otra parte, la de la persona que obra con maldad contra alguien para prevalecer ella misma; algunos calificativos podrían ser: *saboteadora*, *cainita*, *traidora*, *corrupta*, *bellaca*, *perversa*, *malasangre*, *malparida*, *sabandija*, *déspota*, *cínica*... Así como [los propuestos por blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-a-la-persona-que-boicotea-una-acci%C3%B3n-para-luego-vanagloriarse-de-q#comment34224_21770): *vil*, *infame*, *tramposa*, *timadora*, *farsante*.

En ciertos casos y según el contexto, algunas de las anteriores podrían bastar para describir a tal persona. Al final, como todo, va a depender de qué parte del comportamiento de la persona quieras resaltar, y del contexto. Si se entiende que el objetivo saboteado era una apuesta o acuerdo entre dos partes, entonces *tramposa* cuadraría bien. Si está abusando de su posición para anular tus esfuerzos, entonces sería *corrupta* o *déspota*... etc.
El [capitán Haddock](http://es.tintin.com/personnages/show/id/46/page/0/0/el-capitan-haddock) (eterna fuente de inspiración en estas lides) probablemente las usaría [todas juntas](http://www.sepionet.es/tintinofilia/imagenes/18_stock_de_coque/insultos.jpg) :)

Pero en mi opinión, la palabra que mejor unifica ambos sentidos, es la que te propongo al principio: **necio**, **necia**.

Comment: Gracias walen por la respuesta y por esta forma tan original de mostrar definiciones anidadas :) Me gustan las opciones pero me parecen demasiado genéricas, me da que la lengua debe tener por allí perdida una palabra más específica para un caso así.

Comment: Agorero es muy buena, no se me había ocurrido, pero esa persona también es vil, infame, tramposa y me falta otra palabra, algo como *timador* o *farsante* pero no exactamente. Y luego meter todo eso en una sola palabra o expresión.

Comment: Jajaja, no es mala idea crear la palabra juntándolas todas pero no suena todo lo fuerte que merece ese tipo. ¿@fedorqui esa persona existe porque le odio mucho ya?

Comment: La de cínico me encaja mucho y se me ocurrió el otro día dándole vueltas (llevo un par de días yo también jaja).

Comment: eGracias, walen. Realmente _necio_ no me venía a la cabeza en este contexto pero tu respuesta demuestra que sí es un buen candidato. Puesto a recabar informaciones, hace un rato [pregunté lo mismo en English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/405720/37429) y de momento hablan de _saboteador_ y de _profecía autocumplida_.

Answer (score 2):

Estás hablando del caso de **una persona** ***vil***

> ***[vil](https://servicios.elpais.com/diccionarios/castellano/vil)*** (mala y despreciable por su falta de sinceridad, por sus acciones y palabras)

Con una actitud, si no ***sádica*** (que supone *una crueldad refinada, con placer de quien la ejecuta*), definitivamente ***[ruin](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WoYnxu0)***

La ruindad está dada por una competencia malsana, que cela tus progresos, y  una complacencia perversa en el fracaso ([**schadenfreude**](http://tripodologia-felina.blogspot.com/2008/06/schadenfreude.html), *alegría por el mal ajeno*, que en castellano es lo más parecido a [***regodeo***](https://servicios.elpais.com/diccionarios/castellano/regodeo)) que tanto deseó, como ***saboteadoramente*** contribuyó a provocar

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_pasivo-agresivo) dice que en la conducta **pasivo-agresiva**, se evita una confrontación directa.

También podemos decir que la persona te está **saboteando**, o está saboteando tu proyecto.  [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WuDGWQ5) dice que el sabotaje es la "oposición u obstrucción disimulada contra proyectos, órdenes, decisiones, ideas, etc."

Otras ideas: Esta persona te **desvirtuó**, **minó** o **erosionó** tu confianza.

En el caso más extremo podemos hablar de *gaslighting* (término basado en la película clásica *Gaslight* de Ingrid Berman y Charles Boyer).  Dice [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacer_luz_de_gas):

> **Hacer luz de gas** es una forma de abuso psicológico que consiste en presentar información falsa para hacer dudar a la víctima de su memoria, de su percepción o de su cordura.​ Puede consistir en negaciones simples por parte del abusador, en el sentido de si determinados eventos ocurrieron o no, o incluso en la escenificación de situaciones extrañas con el fin de desorientar a la víctima.