# Cómo se puede llamar a la actitud de inducir a una persona a hacer algo, y luego quejarse de que esta persona lo haga?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Siempre creí que la palabra que describía esta acción era cinismo. Pero de acuerdo a Google

> cinismo nombre masculino
>
> 1. Actitud de la persona que miente con descaro y defiende o practica de forma descarada, impúdica y deshonesta algo que merece general
>    desaprobación. "cinismo oportunista; cinismo descarado; era un mundo
>    donde la decadencia irreversible y el cinismo elegante se habían
>    convertido en modo de vida estéticamente aceptable"
> 2. Doctrina filosófica fundada por Antístenes (siglo V a. C.) que se caracteriza por el rechazo de los convencionalismos sociales y de la
>    moral comúnmente admitida.

[Cinismo](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=fl3qXZ-gEO2V5OUPjPaH4AE&q=cinismo&oq=cinismo&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i131j0l4j0i131j0l3.242.1157..1452...0.0..0.109.605.5j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i10.W-clXCWSVgU&ved=0ahUKEwif19-IlqHmAhXtCrkGHQz7ARwQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)

Esto no parece ser la palabra que ando buscando. Sería correcto usar cinismo en la situación descripta en el título? Existe otra palabra para hacer referencia a esa actitud?

Comment: ¿Sería aceptable calificar esto como una forma de *gataflorismo*?

Comment: hmm.. encontré esto sobre "La gata flora". Se dice con picardía cuando una persona se queja de todo y aunque hace como que algo no le gusta, si deja de tenerlo, hace de ver que lo echa de menos

Comment: Es una idea bastante amplia. Para mí entraría dentro de la categoría "gata Flora" una persona que primero insistiera en que otra hiciera algo y después se quejara porque lo hizo.

Comment: Si, coincido coloquialmente gataflorismo aplica (aunque la referencia es una broma sexual, y Pablo aclaró que busca una explicación genérica)

Comment: El concepto también se asocia a *manipulación maquiavélica* y perfidia

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando un jefe te ordena hacer algo, y luego se queja de los resultados de eso que te pidio (cuando lo ejecutaste tal cual lo pedia) o por ejemplo algo que me pasó varias veces en las redes sociales, te sugieren usar una funcion (por ejemplo, la opcion de compartir en varios grupos marcando cada grupo en una lista de checkboxs que te dan ellos) y luego quejarse de que "compartiste en muchos grupos" o invita a tus amigos a ver esta pagina y luego te dicen "mandaste muchas invitaciones" o cosas por el estilo y te penalizan.

Comment: Es una especie de juego psicologico?  En ingles una person que hace eso es un *crazy maker*.  Entendi bien tu idea?

Comment: "manipulacion maquiavélica" como que cubre la idea general pero como que tiene una connotación demasiado grande. O sea, de algo terrible. Algo así pero sobre situaciones más mundanas?

Comment: Caso contrario de lo que pregunté en [¿Cómo se dice a la persona que boicotea una acción para luego vanagloriarse de que no haya podido realizarse?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21769/1674)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que describes podría definirse quizás como una

> incitación artera

que es una manera de **manipulación**

> **[Manipular](https://dle.rae.es/manipular)**
>   
>   3. tr. Intervenir con medios hábiles y, a veces, arteros, en la política, en el mercado, en la información, etc., con distorsión de la verdad o la justicia, y al servicio de intereses particulares.

Podría tratarse de un caso general de

> **[Maquiavelismo](https://dle.rae.es/maquiavelismo?m=form)** 
>   2. m. Modo de proceder con astucia, doblez y perfidia.

Donde 
[perfidia](https://dle.rae.es/perfidia?m=form) es

> 1. f. Deslealtad, traición o quebrantamiento de la fe debida.

Supongo que también puedes estar aludiendo a una actitud neurótica posible de solicitar algo y acusar de ese mismo algo, no tomando responsabilidad del pedido ni reconociéndose autor originario de la acción. (Debería ampliar sobre la manera en que cierta rama de la Psicología nombra e interpreta esas conductas)

En Argentina se estila nombrar como "**histeriqueo**" al acto de seducir, —incitar y retraerse—, negándose posteriormente a la reacción provocada por el interés originalmente manifiesto. (Ver [esta descripción coloquial](https://www.serargentino.com/gente/asi-somos/el-histeriqueo) (`...una persona histérica es la que quiere algo pero niega que lo quiere, o la que quiere algo y después no y mañana otra vez sí.`)

PD: Como argentino podrás ver que la [definición de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=histeriqueo) de este americanismo (`Coqueteo con indecisión simulada y haciéndose de rogar`), si bien correcta, se queda un poco corta al no consignar la frecuente negación posterior

Comment: Es posible que la actitud descripta quizás pueda relacionarse además con el término anglosajón **gaslighting** `Gaslighting is a form of psychological manipulation in which a person seeks to sow seeds of doubt in a targeted individual or in members of a targeted group, making them question their own memory, perception, and sanity. Using persistent denial, misdirection, contradiction, and lying, gaslighting involves attempts to destabilize the victim and delegitimize the victim's beliefs` (en https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting)

Comment: En este caso mi pregunta no tiene que ver con relaciones amorosas (por lo de histeriqueo)

Comment: Bien. 
Igual, el concepto de histeriqueo puede extenderse a una relación general en donde una parte solicita/invita y luego niega/se sustráe